# MapBox Static Map API - Zoom Level/Bounds

Tags: google-maps, maps, zooming, mapbox, bounds

I am exploring replacing a Google Maps Static Maps call with MapBox.  With Google, you can retrieve a static map w/o specifying a center or a zoom level, and it will find the zoom level and center that fits your markers.  I am looking for the same with MapBox but am unable to find it.  Does anyone know how to make this work.  I'm also open to calculating extents and figuring out the zoom level if anyone has a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see the [geo-viewport](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/static-map-from-bounds-with-geo-viewport/) and [geojson-extent](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/static-map-from-geojson-with-geo-viewport/) examples for turning extents into URLs for the Mapbox Static API.